# Using cmake with fortran

Tags: cmake, fortran

As good as cmake is claimed to be, its documentation seems to leave a lot to be desired (unless I'm totally failing at understanding the basics).

I'm trying to write a cmake file for a set of fortran programs which also depend on some other libraries (which are already compiled for my system, but I will want to make a cmake file for these libraries too).

A lot of the commands which I've found in examples online don't appear in the official docs, which is a bit disconcerting.. for example, http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample contains the line

```
get_filename_component (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME ${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER} NAME)
```

yet when I include this in my own CMakeLists.txt I get an error

```
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_fortran_COMPILER
```

What am I missing?!

**Edit: current CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

enable_language(fortran)
project(fortranTest)
get_filename_component (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME ${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER} NAME)
```

**Edit 2**

I still haven't worked out how to include dependent libraries.

Comment: Did you `ENABLE_LANGUAGE(Fortran)` before you do anything? We successfully use CMake on a very large Fortran fluid-dynamics code with little issue (related to Fortran anyway).

Comment: Also, can you edit your post to include your CMakeLists.txt? The error has a lower case `f` in `fortran` while your example line has an uppercase `F`. Additionally, there are better ways to do what the example is trying to do with that information, for instance `if(${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Intel")` which protects you in case the executable is named funny (like on Cray systems where it is wrapped with `ftn`).

Comment: @tpg2114 Yes, I do - I've edited my question to show what I've currently got

Comment: It needs to be `Fortran` not `fortran` in the `enable_language()` call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The language names are case sensitive. As posted, I get:

```
~/cmt> cmake ./
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_fortran_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_fortran_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/home/tgallagher/cmt/CMakeFiles/CMakefortranCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:CMakefortranInformation.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_fortran_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
^C
```

However, by changing the file to (note it is `Fortran` and not `fortran` in `enable_language()`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

enable_language(Fortran)
project(fortranTest)
get_filename_component (Fortran_COMPILER_NAME ${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER} NAME)
```

You get:

```
~/cmt> cmake ./
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
^C
```

Which, if permitted to finish, would work as expected. However, there are better ways to identify the compiler for the purposes of determining compiler flags. The method used in the cited example only works on systems where the compiler is not wrapped, which means systems that don't invoke the compiler through something like `mpif90` or `ftn` on Cray. A better method is to check:

```
if(${CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Intel")
...
endif()
```

The list of possible names can be found by inspecting the file in the CMake Module directory `Modules/CMakeFortranCompilerId.F.in`

Comment: Thanks :) I'd read that commands were case-insensitive, I had also (wrongly!) assumed that this meant the whole file was case-insensitive